# setState works but redux store update doesn't

Tags: reactjs

First, I want to mention that the only thing I'm changing between two approaches is setState vs going through the Redux store. Not changing anything else i.e. components, etc.

If I use the setState approach, I can close my modal but if I go through the store, it doesn't close. Any idea why?

Here's my reducer:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    modals: {
        "modal1": { isDisplayed: true },
        "modal2": { isDisplayed: false }
    }
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case types.SET_IS_DISPLAYED_MODAL : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                modals: action.modals
            })

        default: return state
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the two versions of my onClick action that is supposed to close the modal.

This is the setState version and it works:

```
displayModal(modalId, value)
{
    let modals = this.props.modals;
    modals[modalId].isDisplayed = value;
    return setState({modals: modals});
}
```

And here's the version that goes through the redux store and it does NOT close my modal.

```
displayModal(modalId, value)
{
    let modals = this.props.modals;
    modals[modalId].isDisplayed = value;
    return this.props.actions.displayModal(modals);
}
```

There's not much to the action but here it is:

```
export const displayModal = (modals) => {
    return {
        type: types.SET_IS_DISPLAYED_MODAL,
        modals
    };
}
```

Just so you see how it looks in my component, here it is:

```
render() {

  return(
    <div>
       <div>Some info...</div>
       {this.props.modals["modal1"].isDisplayed
        ? <Modal1 />
        : null}

       {this.props.modals["modal2"].isDisplayed
        ? <Modal2 />
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

BTW, I know that I'm hitting the action and the reducer. I also know that if I put a debugger in my mapStateToProps, I'm hitting it with updated state for my modals. So I know both the action and the reducer are doing what they're supposed to.

UPDATE:
I just tried something and this fixed the issue. I added last line to mapStateToProps and updated the section in my component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        modals: state.modals,
        isModal1Displayed: state.modals["modal1"].isDisplayed // Just added this line
    }
}
```

And changed the code in my component to:

```
render() {

  return(
    <div>
       <div>Some info...</div>
       {this.props.isModal1Displayed
        ? <Modal1 />
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you add the part of your code where you are connecting the component

Comment: Just updated the original post. Instead of checking this.props.modals["modal1"].isDisplayed, I created a new prop for it in mapStateToProps. I think it looks a bit funky in mapStateToProps but it's working fine. Any idea why the initial code was failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **never mutate** state in Redux reducer - it must be a pure function to work and detect changes correctly. Same rules apply to objects which you get with props.

You must change your code so you only dispatch an action to the store and reduce it to a new state.

First, dispatch an action:

```
displayModal(modalId, value)
{
    this.props.actions.displayModal(modalId, value);
}
```

Your action will carry information which modal to hide or show:

```
export const displayModal = (modalId, value) => {
    return {
        type: types.SET_IS_DISPLAYED_MODAL,
        modalId,
        value
    };
}
```

Then you can reduce it:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.SET_IS_DISPLAYED_MODAL : 
            return Object.assign({}, state, 
            {   
                modals: Object.assign({}, state.modals, 
                {
                    [action.modalId]: { isDisplayed: action.value }
                })
            })

        default: return state
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of boilerplate here now. With ES6 and ES7 you can rewrite your reducer with the [object spread operator](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) or you can use [Immutable.js library](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js), which will help you with setting properties deep in the hierarchy.

Reducer with object spread operator looks like this:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.SET_IS_DISPLAYED_MODAL : 
            return {
                ...state,
                modals: {
                    ...state.modals,
                    [action.modalId]: { isDisplayed: action.value }
                }
            }

        default: return state
    }
}
```

You may ask yourself why your fix works. Let me explain.
You change a modal state when you dispatch an action to the Redux by mutating state in place `modals[modalId].isDisplayed = value`. After that the action is dispatched, reduced and `mapToProps` gets called again. There is probably reference check in `connect` higher order component and you have mutated the `modal` but not the `modals` object so it has the same reference = your component doesn't re-render. By adding a `isModal1Displayed` field you are actually disabling optimizations because there is boolean comparison, not a reference check and your component rerenders.

I hope it will help you with understanding Redux and it's principles.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused. I understand and agree with the first part of your response. When I go thru the redux store, I'm not mutating the state at all - as you can see in my reducer code. I read the second part of your response a few times where you talked about why my fix works but I couldn't understand your point. The only difference is that in my fix, I'm assigning the isDisplayed value of modal1 to a new prop in mapStateToProps as opposed to accessing its value (this.props.modals[modal1].isDisplayed) inside the component. In either case, the value is retrieved from the modals object.

Comment: Cont'd: The fact that in both approaches, I pull my value from the modals prop tells me that my action/reducer code works fine and updates the state of modals successfully. I'm just not sure why I can't access isDisplayed for modal1 using this.props.modals[modal1].isDisplayed inside my component.

Comment: It's hard to explain because it requires knownledge how Redux internals work, especially `connect` component. You mutate state in `displayModal` by doing `modals[modalId].isDisplayed = value;` and because `modals` is an object it still points to / references the same memory location. Later, when your action is processed, Redux tries re-render your component but sees that `modals` === `modals` and does nothing in that case. That's why your component did not update.

Comment: I think you're saying I'm mutating the state for modal1 even though I assign it to a new variable -- in the line "let modals = this.props.modals;" Then my question is how am I going to change the value of isDisplayed without mutating the state? And how does that explain why it works if I create a new prop for modal1 in mapStateToProps.

Comment: Your reducer resulted in the same `modals` object and in the [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js) of `connect` there is a check `if (this.stateProps && shallowEqual(nextStateProps, this.stateProps)) return false` which basically checks if `modals` after reduction === `modals` before ONLY BY REFERENCE and KEY EQUALITY without checking inner items' deep fields: `modal1`, `modal2` - that's why it didn't detect change of `isDisplayed` value. See [shallowEqual source](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/utils/shallowEqual.js)

Comment: I was thinking about using Object.assign to create a new modals object in my displayModal callback function -- instead of using let modals = this.props.modals;. But if I'm understanding your theory, that still wouldn't guarantee that the state change will be detected because keys will be the same -- though reference should not be. Are you saying the only way to update the state is to use the double Object.assign in the reducer -- as in your answer?

Comment: The way it works is that a boolean true !== false no matter where it is stored. Object references are compared differently. By adding that field you made the `shallowEqual` return false and process with component update.
In order to not mutate state if you want to keep your original reducer you can try this:

displayModal(modalId, value)
{
        let modals = Object.assign({}, state.modals,
        {
            [modalId]: { isDisplayed: value }
        })
        return this.props.actions.displayModal(modals);
}

You must in fact copy two times - the modfied item and collection

Comment: Wow! This is very interesting and useful information. I do appreciate it. Also, I just tried your code and it works. Just so I'm 100% clear, when I thought I created a new copy of my modals by let modals = this.props.modals, I really wasn't creating a new copy at all because it's still referencing the same object in memory. Is that right?

Comment: `let modals = this.props.modals;` - this still points to the same object :( You must copy with Object.assign or spread operator. Even when you copy the object it's inner items will still point to themselves so you must actually copy every updated item.
That's main problem with immutable in current implementations. Please take a look at [Immutable.js setIn function](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map). It will reduce much hassle and make Redux happy about updates whenever something changes.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)